# Retrieve Roll and Pitch rotation

Tags: vectors, rotations, quaternions

I need to retrieve Roll and Pitch (but not Yaw) rotation values from rotation matrix (or euler angles, or quaternion, input can be different, fortunately, it can be converted from one form to another).

###### [Info table]

- X points Left.
- Y points Up.
- Z points Forward.
- Rotation around local X axis is Pitch.
- Rotation around local Y axis is Yaw.
- Rotation around local Z axis is Roll.

If I just use Euler Angles then, in some situations, I get wrong values.

As I think, this due to rotation can be represented with multiple variations of Euler Angles, so it breaks when rotation around X axis (Pitch) and Z axis (Roll) is represented also using Y axis (Yaw).

[gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byZK9.gif)

(How it works | How it should be, but I need rotation without Yaw axis)

Also algorithm is running in time, so, solutions, computing some delta rotation, are also accepted.

Comment: Very unclear, what is your question?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace , I need formula/algorithm to get Roll and Pitch values from input (euler angles, quaternion, rotation matrix, any form that you prefer to use in formula). I can't just convert input to euler angles and use them because euler angles have multiple ways of representing the same rotation, including ones that use Yaw to represent rotation around Pitch/Roll, but I don't have Yaw axis. I can provide more technical details of project, but I don't think that they will be useful.

Comment: Please phrase your question differently: What information (values) are given and what information are you looking for (what do you want to find)?